# How do I change the background of the title in the action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

"https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzjG3.png"

I want to know how do i change the background of the title in the actionbar? (All of the space that is white should be blue like the actionbar)

Comment: have you text view has background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the Toolbar background color, use `android:background` on your layout XML. If you mean title font color, use `android:textColorPrimary` on your styles.xml file

Comment: i actually mean the background of the text it's self. How do i change that?